# how can i do a join between two classes with parse PHP SDK?

Tags: php, parsing, join, sdk

I need to know how can I do a join because the Parse guide is incomplete: https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#relations-using-join-tables

The problem is that we are some people from different accounts using an App and I can't read the data that other acount put on the database. I imagine that this could be done doing a Join between the users table and the custom table.

Comment: Have you tried asking on their developer forum given there is no documentation that seems like the correct action.

Comment: Yes but i'm still waiting for their answer